# Dragon Naturally Speaking in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, python, wine, speech-recognition

I'm trying to get [Dragon Naturally Speaking](http://www.nuance.com/) working through Ubuntu....

I set it up in virtualbox, but i found it incredibly tough to access its features through Linux. I know there is a way to do it through wine, because this dude did a pretty sick hack for speech recognition in python. 
 [YouTube.com: Using Python to Code by Voice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI)

Also i know theres a neat little python hack called dragonfly that works. My overall goal here is to create my own commands using my keyboard (piano) that correspond to cool functions like unlocking my computer or something (imagine how cool it would be if your password was the noise the guy in the movie Contact plays for the aliens or something like that).

Arbitrary references aside, this is my first post on the forums so please go easy on me. I 'm also relatively new to Ubuntu and the Linux format, but if someone could walk me through the steps to get dragon naturally speaking 12 premium edition working on Ubuntu's latest version(whatever i downloaded like 3 weeks ago) I'm pretty sure I can struggle through making some custom macros myself.

I have Googled and tried a number of different approaches through wine, but, none have been successful thus far.

Cheers!

Comment: "I know there is a way to do it through wine, because this dude". He does not use Wine. He uses Virtual Box. Dragon runs on Windows host, Linux is guest.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Platypus](http://thenerdshow.com/platypus.html). This should do what you want, translating voice commands from Dragon Speak running in Wine to Linux keystrokes.

It's not easy to install, nor easy to configure. You are expected to know how to compile software and hunt dependencies, so if you are a beginner be ready for a though ride and lots of trial and error.