# Will Dragon Naturally Speaking in windows vbox on ubuntu 16.04 machine?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, text-to-speech, speech-recognition

Following up on [this post by Joe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435651/will-dragon-naturally-speaking-work-in-a-windows-7-vm-running-in-ubuntu) so I can tag it with DNS.

I'm in the same situation -- only want win for DNS.  Personally, I'm not interested in controlling a desktop (as in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353167/dragon-naturally-speaking-in-ubuntu)).  I liked DNS under win just to create content in the dictation box and then copy to Writer or an email and do formatting there. Not a full use of DNS, but it was an advantage over typing.

I saw the poor ratings for DNS in WineHQ. I hadn't heard of Playonlinux until today -- you need both that and wine on ubuntu? I don't understand either answer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473993/run-windows-and-ubuntu-in-parallel).

I had a good experience trying ubuntu on a vbox under win (and therefore switched to ubuntu-only).

So I'm wondering **how well** DNS (any version) works in a win vbox on an Ubuntu physical box before spending hours installing vbox and DNS (will my old license work?) -- and playonlinux? -- only to find that it doesn't work.

**Does anyone run DNS successfully in a win vbox on an ubuntu machine (16.04)?**  If so, **does it** at least allow you to use the dictation box as above, and **how did you set it up**?

Answer (score 0):

That was my question also. So I’ve decided to try and it works for me – Dragon Naturally Speaking 13 installed in a Windows 7 VirtualBox 6.0 running in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, eg: there is an "aenea" tool at "https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/aenea" where a Linux host uses Dragon in a Windows VM. But don't expect it to be easy to setup, or to have the full suite of Dragon tools, since dialog boxes such as for editing vocabulary and spelling words will be stuck inside Windows.